# TFS API Pulling changesets of a certain IterationId

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am trying to pull work item information from Team Foundation Server.  I have a working program that pulls *all* WorkItems.  I am attempting to only pull WorkItems *that belong to a specific iteration (`IterationId`)*.

One way to do this that I have tried... is to produce a list of all the WorkItems and then filter out lines that have an `IterationID` that matches the user given iteration.  The problem with this is that it takes a very long time to pull all changes.  Most of my iterations only contain 5-10 WorkItems.

My program that pulls *all* changes:

```
Uri tfsUri = new Uri(projectCollection.Uri.ToString());
        VersionControlServer controlServer = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        var hHistory = controlServer.QueryHistory("$/MyPath/",
                                                    VersionSpec.Latest,
                                                    0,
                                                    RecursionType.Full,
                                                    String.Empty,
                                                    null,
                                                    VersionSpec.Latest,
                                                    int.MaxValue,
                                                    false,
                                                    false,
                                                    true);
foreach (Changeset change in hHistory)
{
    cfChangedFiles = change.Changes;
    foreach (WorkItem wi in change.WorkItems)
    {
        strInput = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(GetStreamAsByteArray(cfChangedFiles[i].Item.DownloadFile()));
        Console.WriteLine("Iteration ID: " + wi.IterationId.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Title: " + wi.Title.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("ChangesetID: " + change.ChangesetId.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("SourceText:\t\t" + strInput); //EDIT NEW
        //...Print Other Things...
    }
}
```

I have also tried pulling the information using `WorkItemStore.Query`:

```
WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)projectCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
// Run a query.
WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemStore.Query(
    "Select [State], [Title] " +
    "From WorkItems Where [System.IterationId] ='73'");
foreach(WorkItem wi in queryResults)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Iteration ID: " + wi.IterationId.ToString());
    /*...Print Other Things...
}
```

The problem with the above code is that I cannot pull certain things (like the Source Text).

---

**Similar Question:**
[TFS API - slow foreach changeset iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109315/tfs-api-slow-foreach-changeset-iteration) - This question is similar in that the OP's program loads very slowly.  However, the answer given is already implemented in my program.  This also still pulls *all* changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question.  The 6th and 7th parameters of QueryHistory are the *starting* ChangesetID and *ending* ChangesetID.

```
Uri tfsUri = new Uri(projectCollection.Uri.ToString());
    VersionControlServer controlServer = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
    var hHistory = controlServer.QueryHistory("$/MyPath/",
                                                VersionSpec.Latest,
                                                0,
                                                RecursionType.Full,
                                                String.Empty,
                                                VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(changeset.ChangesetId.ToString(), null),
                                                VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(changeset.ChangesetId.ToString(), null),
                                                int.MaxValue,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                true);
```

I used [WIQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130306(v=vs.120).aspx) to select all ChangesetIDs that correspond to a given IterationID.  Then, I looped through the above code for each ChangesetID.  This allowed my application to only load the changes for my given ChangesetID.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably go with option 2, run a query for all Work Items in that iteration path and then find any associated changesets.  I assume it would be faster.

In your foreach loop wi.Links should allow you to get the ChangesetId.

From: [How can I query work items and their linked changesets in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956570/how-can-i-query-work-items-and-their-linked-changesets-in-tfs)

```
foreach (WorkItem workItem in workItemCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("WI: {0}, Title: {1}", workItem.Id, workItem.Title);
    foreach (var changeset in
        workItem.Links
            .OfType<ExternalLink>()
            .Select(link => artifactProvider
                .GetChangeset(new Uri(link.LinkedArtifactUri))))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "CS: {0}, Comment: {1}",
            changeset.ChangesetId,
            changeset.Comment);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the response.  I have made an edit to my original question.  I also need things like text of the changeset's downloaded file.  The second option has no way to download the change (from what I can tell).  I still appreciate the answer!

Comment: No problem.  What about using "foreach (var change in changeset.Changes)" and then you can use "change.Item.ServerItem" to get the server path or "change.Item.DownloadFile()" to grab the file?

Comment: I am actually doing something very similar where I use `change.Item.ServerItem` and `.DownloadFile()`.  The issue is that it is still being called for all changes.  Which is causing the working program to take 12~ minutes to run.  I am really trying to find a way to download the file using my second attempt/your answer.  If not using `workItemCollection` (which runs very quickly), find a way to only pull certain changes from the first block of code.  Currently it pulls all changes.